# While loop in bash to read a file skips first 2 characters of THIRD Line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ffmpeg

```
#bin/bash
INPUT_DIR="$1"
INPUT_VIDEO="$2"
OUTPUT_PATH="$3"
SOURCE="$4"
DATE="$5"

INPUT="$INPUT_DIR/sorted_result.txt"
COUNT=1
initial=00:00:00
while IFS= read -r line; do
  OUT_DIR=$OUTPUT_PATH/$COUNT
  mkdir "$OUT_DIR"
  ffmpeg -nostdin -i $INPUT_VIDEO -vcodec h264 -vf fps=25 -ss $initial -to $line $OUT_DIR/$COUNT.avi
  ffmpeg -i $OUT_DIR/$COUNT.avi -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 $OUT_DIR/$COUNT.wav
  python3.6 /home/Video_Audio_Chunks_1.py $OUT_DIR/$COUNT.wav
  python /home/transcribe.py  --decoder beam --cuda --source $SOURCE --date $DATE --video $OUT_DIR/$COUNT.avi --out_dir "$OUT_DIR"
  COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
  echo "--------------------------------------------------"
  echo $initial
  echo $line
  echo "--------------------------------------------------"
  initial=$line
done < "$INPUT"
```

This is the code I am working on.
The contents of file sorted_results.txt are as follows:

```
00:6:59
00:7:55
00:8:39
00:19:17
00:27:48
00:43:27
```

While reading the file it skips first two characters of the third line i.e. it takes it as `:8:39` which results in the ffmpeg error and the script stops.

However when I only print the variables $INITIAL and $LINE, commenting the `ffmpeg` command the values are printed correctly i.e. same as the file contents.

I think the ffmpeg command is somehow affecting the file reading process or the variable value. BUT I CAN'T UNDERSTAND HOW?

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Please don't put caps letters, even you will post simple post with 3 simple things, sample input, sample output and your effort people will try to help you, kindly correct your post now.

Comment: @YaserSakkaf : I don't know about ffmpeg, so I can only marginally help here, but from the bash viewpoint, I would do two things: Trace the ffmpeg calls (`set -x`), so that you actually see, what information gets passed, and - for the safe side - doublequote the variables in the ffmpeg call, though based on the data you posted, this should not be an issue here. Also, I would dump the content of the variables hexadecimal, in case there is a hidden control character: Put after your mkdir a `echo -n "/$initial/$line/" | xxd`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your bash [**read** builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) and the second ffmpeg command (for the audio) both read from STDIN, that is why they interfere with each other.  You can either also specify **-nostdin** there or use another file descriptor (here number 3 is used) for read:

```
  while IFS= read -r -u 3 line; do
    ...
  done 3< "$INPUT"
```