# How create dynamic folder with input structure in shell script when using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, shell, ffmpeg

i have created this shell script to encode videos using ffmpeg. i need to maintain the folder structure of input and output folder automatically when i run this script.

**Problem** : As of now, it moves all videos to root of destination directory. it need to create  subfolder and output file should save in it.

**Input folder:**

```
Folder1
--sub_folder
---video1.mkv
---video2.ts
---video3.mp4
Folder2
---cat.mkv
---mouse.ts
---train.mp4
```

**Expected Output folder:**

```
Folder1
--sub_folder
---video1.mp4
---video2.mp4
---video3.mp4
Folder2
---cat.mp4
---mouse.mp4
---train.mp4
```

**Code :**

```
srcDir=$1
destDir=$2

for filename in $(find "$srcDir" -type f); do

        basePath=${filename%.*}
        baseName=${basePath##*/}

        audioformat=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$filename")
        videoformat=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$filename")

        if [ "$audioformat" == "aac" ] &&  [ "$videoformat" == "h264" ] ; then
                echo $filename
                echo $audioformat + $videoformat
                ffmpeg -i "$filename" -y -c:v copy -c:a copy "$destDir"/"$baseName.mp4" -hide_banner -loglevel warning 
        elif [ "$audioformat" == "aac" ] &&  [ "$videoformat" != "h264" ] ; then
                echo $filename
                echo $audioformat + $videoformat
                ffmpeg -i "$filename" -y -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "$destDir"/"$baseName.mp4" -hide_banner -loglevel warning 
        elif [ "$audioformat" != "aac" ] &&  [ "$videoformat" == "h264" ] ; then
                echo $filename
                echo $audioformat + $videoformat
                ffmpeg -i "$filename" -y -c:v copy -c:a aac "$destDir"/"$baseName.mp4" -hide_banner -loglevel warning 
        else
                echo $filename
                echo $audioformat + $videoformat
                ffmpeg -i "$filename" -y -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "$destDir"/"$baseName.mp4" -hide_banner -loglevel warning 
        fi


done
```

if possible , check whether this code looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Replace `for ... ; do` with:

```sh
    find "$srcDir" -type f |
    while IFS= read -r filename; do
        relPath="${filename#${srcDir}}"
        relPath=$(dirname "${relPath#/}")
        tgtDir="$destDir/$relPath"
        mkdir -p "$tgtDir"
```

and then replace `"$destDir"/"$baseName.mp4"` with `"$tgtDir/$baseName.mp4"`. Use `=` to test for string equality, not `==`; see `help test`.

**EDIT**:
[shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) suggests you use `ffmpeg -nostdin ...` to prevent ffmpeg from swallowing stdin -- which could interfere with `read`, cf. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51247482/14403369).

Comment: works good but,on else condition the $filename strips first few characters automatically.

Comment: lets say for example, main-video/first/sub/1.mp4 is changing to n-video/first/sub/1.mp4.

Comment: Are you saying that the first 3 characters of `$relPath` always disappear? In that case please give an example of `$srcDir` and `$filename`.

Comment: $srcDir = sample-videos-segment/
$filename = sample-videos-segment/New/First/c5eb8d98-5d4e-4d00-8c4e-f44aac599e60.mp4

Comment: not the first 3 characters it automatically truncates, random n characters

in the above case: -videos-segment/New/First/c5eb8d98-5d4e-4d00-8c4e-f44aac599e60.mp4

sample is removed

Comment: There is nothing in the code I posted which can truncate `$srcDir` or `$relPath` and I cannot reproduce the error you mention. I suggest you post your edited code.

Comment: it mostly occurs on else part

Comment: The code you posted looks OK to me. Do any of the source filenames contain characters `*` or `backslash` ? If not, add `printf '%s\n' "$relPath" "$tgtDir"` to the first lines of the `while` loop to pinpoint the error location.

Comment: <https://www.shellcheck.net> suggests you use `ffmpeg -nostdin ...` to prevent ffmpeg from swallowing stdin (which could interfere with `read` and explain the error).